# WPF Scroll bar skin

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

Is there any way to change all scrollbars so I can make them look less windows? I don't dislike windows but in this case the scrollbar just looks stupid..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All WPF controls are skinnable by their control templates.  Its pretty simple to do, but it may take a little time to fully grasp how to do it.

[Here's an example on MSDN for skinning the scrollbar.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I usually apply the SimpleScrollviewer/SimpleListbox/etc. when Im inside Blend. You need to go to the Asset Library (">>"),Simple Styles, choose one of the elements. Because Simple elements have more "stuff" inside, its easier to change it.